# Max resolution for video in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flvplayback

I'm working on a standalone app that displays high-resolution video with other movie clips. I am using Flash FLVPlayback component. Not sure what is the max dimensions of video that can be played in Flash?

I'm trying to display a locally stored MP4 video with the dimensions of 5760 x 1080, which is well under the max canvas area limit, but is not displaying properly. I can see a green rectangle where the video should be displayed.

Comment: Try using **stageVideo** instead **FLVPlayBack**.

Comment: stageVideo will work with Flash? Or, is it for Flext/AIR only?